# Is there any facebook api for c# available to use in windows phone for getting nearby places(atms/hotels)?

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8

Is there any facebook c# api available to use in windows phone for getting nearby places(atms/hotels/hospitals/famous places etc) ?

Answer (score 0):

**No**, there is no built-in API endpoint available for that, but you are more than welcome to download the [Facebook SDK](http://nuget.org/packages/Facebook/5.3.2.0) and use it to connect to the Graph API.

Comment: WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
            myWebClient.DownloadStringCompleted +=     myWebClient_DownloadStringCompleted;
            Uri uri = new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=location&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000");
            myWebClient.DownloadStringAsync(uri);